# Java reflection pass a method as a parameter of another method?

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

I can get a list of methods that are annotated no problem...

```
Method[] m = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
```

Now I would like to pass the method[x] to a function. For instance...

```
router.get("/").handler(RoutingContext handler)
```

I would like to pass it to the handler as a method reference.

In java 8 we can just do `router.get("/").handler(this::myMethod)`

**Updated example:**

```
public void myFunction() throws Exception {

    Router routes = Router.router(...);

    Handler<RoutingContext> handler = this::myHandler;
    routes.route("/").handler(handler);
    routes.route("/someOtherRoute").handler(this::anotherHandler);

}

public void myHandler(final RoutingContext rcs) {
    rcs.doSomething();
}
```

I would like to annotate the function myHandler so I can find it reflectively and add it to the "Router". So with reflection I can get a list of methods that have been annotated no problem and then for each one add it to my router...

So say I have some "web" anotations...

```
@GET
public void myHandler(final RoutingContext rcs) {
    rcs.doSomething();
}

@POST
public void anotherHandler(final RoutingContext rcs) {
    rcs.doSomething();
}
```

I can list these methods using reflection. Cool no problem. But then I would like to pass them as method references to router.handler() as shown in the above example...

If you haven't guessed it it for a web framework and no I wont release it to the wild not like we need another one. It's for learning purposes lol.

**Update**

Router is of type: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/blob/master/vertx-web/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/web/Router.java and

And hander is part of vertx.io

Comment: Are you looking for how to get the specific method by name in reflection?

Comment: No, that I know. But I want to pass the method reference/lambda to another function...

Comment: Your question may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely. Consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: Not sure about that. I'm not sure how to get to it. Basically I would like to to figure which methods are in a class and then pass them to the other function. It's a reflection issue. But I'm not sure how it's done or even possible.

Comment: Learn how to invoke a method reflectively.  Then pass a lambda that invokes the method reflectively.

Comment: I know how to invoke a method reflectively also. Though not sure how it all ties in to method references. Can you get method references with reflections?

Comment: It kind of depends on *which* method reference you want.  Java is still strongly typed.  So if you want a method that takes a `RountingContext` as a method type, then that's what you look for reflectively, and that's what you need as a method parameter.  As mentioned, a little clearer example would help us help you.

Comment: Although now I'm looking at `MethodHandles.lookup()`;  there's some weird stuff in there I didn't know about.

Comment: Well, thank you for updating your question.  I could still use an example that compiles though;  there's too much missing for me to want to guess at it.

Comment: Ouf that involves a bunch of other dependencies and such. Ok let me see what I can do. But basically I know how to get my methods reflectively. It's just how to pass them as method references.

Comment: It doesn't have to do anything useful, just compile.  Pay attention to the number and types of parameters being passed though, I think you may have made a mistake there, something doesn't look quite right.

Comment: No it's fine on my side it compiles...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass a lambda expression performing the reflective invocation, e.g.

```
routes.route("/").handler(rc -> { try { method.invoke(this, rc); }
    catch (ReflectiveOperationException ex) { throw new RuntimeException(ex);}
} );
```

which does the job.

Alternatively, you can indeed generate an instance equivalent to a method reference, which requires deeper knowledge about reflective operations (and the `Handler` interface which you didn’t post). E.g. to generate a `Consumer<RoutingContext>` invoking your `method` you can use:

```
MethodHandles.Lookup l=MethodHandles.lookup();
Consumer<RoutingContext> c=(Consumer<RoutingContext>)
  LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(l, "accept",
    MethodType.methodType(Consumer.class, getClass()),
    MethodType.methodType(void.class, Object.class), l.unreflect(method),
    MethodType.methodType(void.class, RoutingContext.class))
  .getTarget().invoke(this);
```

To generate a `Handler` instead, you have to replace the occurrences of `Consumer` with `Handler` and `"accept"` with the name of the functional method of `Handler`. Also, if `Handler`’s type parameter has a lower bound other than `Object`, you have to replace `Object.class` with the raw type of the lower bound.

The [documentation of `LambdaMetaFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html) is very exhaustive and there are [related Q&A’s on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=LambdaMetaFactory) providing more information, however, if you have any doubts, just stick to the reflective invocation…

Comment: Ok ill try it out. But if ot helps... Router is of https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/blob/master/vertx-web/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/web/Router.java and handler also is part of vertx...

Comment: So `Handler` differs from `Consumer` only in the method’s name, i.e. you have to replace `"accept"` with `"handle"`…

Answer (score 0):

When you use a method reference, the type of the reference is a class that implements an interface type (specifically, a *functional interface*).  In your case, it looks like the type of your method reference is `Handler<RoutingContext>`.

You seem to be looking for a way to convert a `Method` to a functional interface of your choosing.  I don't know of a direct way to do that, but you could try something like

```
public class HandlerFromMethod implements Handler<RoutingContext> {

    final private Method method;

    public HandlerFromMethod(Method m) {
        method = m; 
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(final RoutingContext rcs) {
        method.invoke(null, rcs);
    }
}
```

Now if you have a `Method` m, `new HandlerFromMethod(m)` creates an object that can be used as a `Handler<RoutingMethod>`, and will invoke `m` when called.

If the method is an instance method, then you'll want to add another parameter to the constructor to specify the instance it will operate on, and use that as the first parameter to `invoke`.

I'm assuming that the method in `Handler` is named `apply`; if it's something else, then change the name in the above code.

**Disclaimer:** I haven't tested this.

Comment: Since we assume that `Handler` is a functional interface, there is no need to fall back to an ordinary class instead of using a lambda expression. The only reason, not to use it, would be the bigger size due to the required exception handling, however, you left off that part in your code anyway. Besides, it’s clear from the OP’s context, that the target methods are instance methods, so passing `null` as target instance won’t work.

Comment: Right, but using a separate class may make things more readable, especially if it will be used a number of times.  YMMV.